# Cholesky decomposition of real symmetric positive semidefinite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

Assuming $A$ is a real symmetric positive semidefinite square matrix, the cholesky decomposition applies only when $A$ is strictly positive definite. Otherwise the algorithm will fail according to documentations of a number of  linear algebra packages including Matlab. However, if I perform an eigen value decomposition $A=V\Lambda V^\top=PP^\top$, where $P=V\sqrt{\Lambda}$, then a QR decomposition $P^\top=QR$, I get $A=PP^{\top}=R^{\top}Q^{\top}QR=LL^\top$, where $L=R^\top$ is a lower triangular matrix. It seems I have obtained a cholesky decomposition of a semidefinite $A$ without any problem. I was wondering if there is anything wrong here? If not, how can I directly obtain the $A=LL^\top$ decomposition without these highly inefficient procedures?

Comment: Nothing is wrong: you can indeed obtain a Cholesky decomposition of a real symmetric positive semidefinite matrix.  However, this decomposition will no longer be unique.  You could get a unique decomposition if you instead take $L$ to be $n \times r$, where $r$ is the rank of $A$ and $A$ is $n \times n$.

Comment: Is there a way to obtain this unique cholesky decomposition directly, without the two-step procedure I use, which seems to be an overkill?